# How to print exception message in C++ with catch(...) {..}

Tags: c++, exception

This is the sample code

```
int main()
{
    string S;
    getline(cin, S);
    try {
        int val = stoi(S);
    } catch(...) {
       // cout << //exception message ; I want to print the exception message. 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to print an exception message in this case ?. The message will show what kind of exception was thrown. I am trying this because , stoi() can throw multiple exceptions and I want to catch all of them and print the type of exception that was thrown, **instead of using a separate catch block for each exception type**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All C++ library exceptions inherit from `std::exception`.

So the simplest thing to do is to catch a reference to it:

```
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
    std::cout << "Caught " << e.what(); << std::endl;
}
```

This will catch all exceptions thrown by `stoi`.

Comment: I tried this. It seems that when exception is thrown the only output is ```stoi```
input string: ```$#%$sto;'```
output: ```Caught Exception: stoi``` . This will do fine. But I guess it can't be more specific unless I use the exact exception type in catch

Comment: `what()`'s message is implementation-defined and depends on the compiler. If all you need is a custom message for one or two specific exceptions it's possible to use `dynamic_cast` to check for them.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot.

Catching with `catch(...)` has two properties.

1. It can capture anything thrown.
2. You don't have access to whatever has been caught.

Which means you cannot use `.what()` on the object caught, because you have no access to it.

If you have a warrant that `std::exception` will be thrown, then you could simply capture `std::exception const&`

```cpp
catch(std::exception const& e){
    std::cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<std::endl;
}
```